# How do I test if a given set is nonempty?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, the given set is:

$S = \{X \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R) | AX + X^{T} A = 0 \}$

So far I know that I need to do the following steps:

- $AX + X^T A = 0$
- Let $X = 0$
- $A(0) + (0)A = 0$
- $0 + 0 = 0$

Is this all I need to do to make sure that the given set is nonempty? I'm not really sure as to why this proves that S is nonempty.

Comment: Looks good to me. To prove that a set is non-empty, you just need to show at least one element exists in the set. You have shown that the zero matrix is in the set, thus the set is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks so much!